# Throwing the fattest people off of an overloaded airplane.

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

Let's say you've got an airplane, and it is low on fuel.  Unless the plane drops 3000 pounds of passenger weight, it will not be able to reach the next airport.  To save the maximum number of lives, we would like to throw the heaviest people off of the plane first.

And oh yeah, there are millions of people on the airplane, and we would like an optimal algorithm to find the heaviest passengers, without necessarily sorting the entire list.

This is a proxy problem for something I'm trying to code in C++.  I would like to do a "partial_sort" on the passenger manifest by weight, but I don't know how many elements I'm going to need.  I could implement my own "partial_sort" algorithm ("partial_sort_accumulate_until"), but I'm wondering if there's any easier way to do this using standard STL.

Comment: If the analogy to human holds you could start by throwing off people that weigh more then X, for instance 120 kg, since those are very likely to be among the fattest people.

Comment: Since throwing out n people is enough, doesn't seem you need to sort anything. Find max then exclude it from the set n times until you loose your 3k pounds.

Comment: Would a Heap/Priority Queue be of any use to you?

Comment: If you know/can estimate the number of passengers you need in advance, you can find the top N ones in one pass, using a buffer of length N. If you don't know the length, you should sort anyway, right?

Comment: Would all passengers cooperate with any step of the algorithm?

Comment: You don't actually need partial_sort, so you should probably take that out of the question title.

Comment: Glad I work in the relational database world where I don't have to think this hard to solve the question in an optimum way.

Comment: topics like this are why i love IT.

Comment: Can I ask which airline this is for? I want to make sure I only fly with them *before* the holiday season - not after I've over indulged myself.

Comment: Passenger cooperation is not required with the proper equipment (like ejector seats with built-in scales).

Comment: @JimFred We could throw those off the plane instead...

Comment: Since you have no way of identifying passengers, how do you decide between passengers who are of equal weight? (which many will be in a  group of 1 million plus) If I have 11 people who weigh exactly 300lbs, and are the heaviest on the plane, which 10 do I chose? Are you explicitly disallowing equal weights? This question goes to Set vs MultiSet vs Map <weight,knt> implementations.

Comment: Please specify what "optimal" means. I believe benchmarking will bear me out, that what is technically elegant will not provide the best performance. Should we agree that minimum run-time is "optimal"?

Comment: This is the best Weight-Lost ads I have seen.

Comment: @RedX: throwing off people that weigh more then X is similar to the  [Dowry Problem/Secretary Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). Mind you on a passenger airplane the total weight of passenger+luggage(+cargo) is [known(/estimated) at takeoff](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/256650/). So a priori we could know what 150% of average passenger weight was.

Comment: This question statement also assumes we know nothing at all a priori about human body weight distribution, i.e. a 1lb person is equally likely to a 1,000lb person.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

One way would be to use a [min heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) ([`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) in C++). Here's how you'd do it, assuming you had a `MinHeap` class.  (Yes, my example is in C#. I think you get the idea.)

```
int targetTotal = 3000;
int totalWeight = 0;
// this creates an empty heap!
var myHeap = new MinHeap<Passenger>(/* need comparer here to order by weight */);
foreach (var pass in passengers)
{
    if (totalWeight < targetTotal)
    {
        // unconditionally add this passenger
        myHeap.Add(pass);
        totalWeight += pass.Weight;
    }
    else if (pass.Weight > myHeap.Peek().Weight)
    {
        // If this passenger is heavier than the lightest
        // passenger already on the heap,
        // then remove the lightest passenger and add this one
        var oldPass = myHeap.RemoveFirst();
        totalWeight -= oldPass.Weight;
        myHeap.Add(pass);
        totalWeight += pass.Weight;
    }
}

// At this point, the heaviest people are on the heap,
// but there might be too many of them.
// Remove the lighter people until we have the minimum necessary
while ((totalWeight - myHeap.Peek().Weight) > targetTotal)
{
    var oldPass = myHeap.RemoveFirst();
    totalWeight -= oldPass.Weight; 
}
// The heap now contains the passengers who will be thrown overboard.
```

According to the standard references, running time should be proportional to `n log k`, where `n` is the number of passengers and `k` is the maximum number of items on the heap. If we assume that passengers' weights will typically be 100 lbs or more, then it's unlikely that the heap will contain more than 30 items at any time.

The worst case would be if the passengers are presented in order from lowest weight to highest. That would require that every passenger be added to the heap, and every passenger be removed from the heap. Still, with a million passengers and assuming that the lightest weighs 100 lbs, the `n log k` works out to a reasonably small number.

If you get the passengers' weights randomly, performance is much better. I use something quite like this for a recommendation engine (I select the top 200 items from a list of several million). I typically end up with only 50,000 or 70,000 items actually added to the heap.

I suspect that you'll see something quite similar: the majority of your candidates will be rejected because they're lighter than the lightest person already on the heap. And `Peek` is an `O(1)` operation.

For a more information about the performance of heap select and quick select, see [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/). Short version: if you're selecting fewer than 1% of the total number of items, then heap select is a clear winner over quick select. More than 1%, then use quick select or a variant like [Introselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Introselect).

Comment: To my reading, SoapBox's answer is the moral equivalent of Jim Mischel's answer.  SoapBox wrote his code in C++, and thus he uses a std::set, which has the same log(N) add time as the MinHeap.

Comment: There is a linear time solution.  I'll add it.

Comment: There's a STL class for a min-heap: `std::priority_queue`

Comment: You could end up throwing too many people off the plane.  When you save the lightest person in the heap, you should also check the second lightest, etc.

Comment: @IronMensan: Read the paragraph below the code. It describes how you prevent throwing too many people overboard.

Comment: @IvyMike: sure he uses a std::set.  But it's on a fixed size (unknown at compile time, but still fixed), so it's O(N+log(c)) = O(N).

Comment: @MooingDuck: Perhaps you misunderstood. My code creates an empty heap, just as SoapBox's code creates an empty set. The major difference, as I see it, is that his code trims the set of excess weight as higher weight items are added, whereas mine maintains the excess and trims it at the end. His set will potentially decrease in size as he moves through the list finding heavier people. My heap stays the same size after it reaches the weight threshold, and I trim it after checking the last item in the list.

Comment: @JimMischel: I think for your algorithm to be correct, you need to check to make sure you can't remove people from the heap after you're done processing everyone.  What happens if you encounter 10 300 pound people, and then you meet 1 3000 pound guy?

Comment: @NeilG: Then the 3,000 lb guy would be put on the heap and one of the 300 lb guys would be removed. When I've seen everybody, the heap will contain nine 300-pounders, and the big guy. What happens next is in the description following the code. I suppose I should write that in code in order to reduce confusion.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're right.  I just looked at the code this time to see what Mooing was doing differently.

Comment: If you have a really large amount of passengers you might want to do the first filling of the list before the main loop and drop the first if (totalWeight < targetTotal){}.

Comment: A great answer. I would optimize it that after each insertion, you should remove as many people as you can - not just the lighter person. Basically, move the last 5 lines inside the 'else if' clause, and delete the first two lines in that clause. When you have 3000 people with weight 1 lb, then 1 person which weight 4000 lb, then a series of people starting with 2 lb and growing slowly - you would like to cleanup the heap after the heavy person, and not at the end.

Comment: A slightly simpler way to achieve the same theoretical result would be to call heapify on the entire set into a min heap (heapify takes n elements and turns them into a heap in `O(n))` and pull off enough until you get just below 3000, or whatever is specified. Runtime is `O(n log k)`, with the same `k` as above.

Comment: @BryceSandlund: That would work, yes. But my experiments (see the last paragraph) showed that calling heapify on the entire set is slower than this method when `k` is very small in relation to `n`. In addition, calling heapify requires that the entire set will fit into memory, whereas this method only requires memory for `k` items.

Comment: I also was incorrect... The runtime with heapify is `O(k log n + n)`. This leads to some very interesting theoretical analysis! I am not surprised at all that for practical solutions heap select is better though.

Comment: Had to get out the paper and pencil for this one! Asymptotically, if `k` is `Θ(1)`, then both algorithms are `Θ(n)`. If `k` is `Θ(n)`, then both algorithms are `Θ(n log n)`. BUT, if k is `ω(1)` and `o(n)` (between the two), then heapify is asymptotically better than heap select. Kind of weird to think of it like this though. Percentages actually don't matter. It's how `k` grows in relation to `n`. So if you keep `k` as `O(log n)` for example, there will be some point in time after increasing `n` where heapify will be heap select.

Answer (score 121):

This won't help for your proxy problem, however:

For 1,000,000 passengers to drop 3000 pounds of weight, each passenger must lose (3000/1000000) = 0.003 lbs per person. That could be achieved through jettisoning every ones shirt, or shoes, or probably even fingernail clippings, saving everyone. This assumes efficient collection and jettison before the weight loss needed increased as the plane used more fuel.

Actually, they don't allow fingernail clippers on board anymore, so that's out.

Comment: Love the ability to look through the problem and find a truly better way.

Comment: I think shoes alone would cover this

Comment: 0.003 lbs is 0.048 oz, which is just under 1/20 of an ounce.  So if a mere one in sixty people on the plane was taking advantage of the three-ounce shampoo rule, you could save the day just by throwing out all that shampoo.

Answer (score 43):

Below is a rather simple implementation of the straightforward solution.  I don't think there is a faster way that is 100% correct.

```
size_t total = 0;
std::set<passenger> dead;
for ( auto p : passengers ) {
    if (dead.empty()) {
       dead.insert(p);
       total += p.weight;
       continue;
    }
    if (total < threshold || p.weight > dead.begin()->weight)
    {
        dead.insert(p);
        total += p.weight;
        while (total > threshold)
        {
            if (total - dead.begin()->weight < threshold)
                break;
            total -= dead.begin()->weight;
            dead.erase(dead.begin());
        }
    }
 }
```

This works by filling up the set of "dead people" until it meets the threshold.  Once the threshold is met, we keep going through the list of passengers trying to find any that are heavier than the lightest dead person.  When we have found one, we add them to the list and then start "Saving" the lightest people off the list until we can't save any more.

In the worst case, this will perform about the same as a sort of the entire list.  But in the best case (the "dead list" is filled up properly with the first X people) it will perform `O(n)`.

Comment: I think you have to update `total` next to `continue;`  Other than that, this is the answer I was going to post.  Super fast solution

Comment: This is the correct answer, this is the fastest answer, this is also the answer with the lowest complexity.

Comment: You could probably squeeze a little more out of it by caching dead.begin() and by rearranging stuff a bit to minimize branching, which on modern processors is quite slow

Comment: dead.begin() is most likely trival and would almost certainly be inlined to just a data access.  But yeah, moving around a few of the ifs would eek out a little more performance by reducing branches... but at probably great cost to readability.

Comment: This is logically elegant, and addresses ALL of the OP's requirements, including not knowing the # of passengers up front. Having spent much of the last 5 months working with STL Maps & Sets though, I'm sure the extensive use of iterators used would cripple performance. Just populate the set, and then iterate from right to left until the sum of the heaviest people is greater than 3,000. A Set of 1 million elements, presented in random order, will load at ~ 30 million/sec on i5||i7 3.4Ghz cores. Iteration at least 100X as slow. KISS will win here.

Answer (score 31):

Assuming all passengers will cooperate: Use a **[parallel sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)**. (see also [this](http://brianpursley.com/Files/CSC204_FinalProject_BrianPursley.pdf))

<strike>[Here is a live demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0u18lOIv0g)</strike>

Update: [Alternative video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30WcPnvfiKE) (jump to 1:00)

Asking pairs of people to compare-exchange - you can't get faster than this.

Comment: This is still a sort and will be O(nlogn). You certainly can get faster, as an O(nlogk) where k << n, solution has been provided.

Comment: @Adam: It's parallel sort. Sorting has a lower bound of O(nlog n) SEQUENTIAL steps. However they can paralleled, so the time complexity can be much lower. see for example http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/ramsey/parasort.pdf

Comment: Well, the OP says "This is a proxy problem for something I'm trying to code in C++." So even if the passengers will cooperate, they won't compute for you. It's a neat idea, but that paper's assumption that you get `n` processors does not hold.

Answer (score 22):

@Blastfurnace was on the right track.  You use quickselect where the pivots are weight thresholds.  Each partition splits one set of people into sets, and returns the total weight for each set of people.  You continue breaking the appropriate bucket until your buckets corresponding to the highest weight people are over 3000 pounds, and your lowest bucket that is in that set has 1 person (that is, it can't be split any further.)

This algorithm is linear time amortized, but quadratic worst case.  I think it is the only **linear time algorithm**.

---

Here's a Python solution that illustrates this algorithm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math
import numpy as np
import random

OVERWEIGHT = 3000.0
in_trouble = [math.floor(x * 10) / 10
              for x in np.random.standard_gamma(16.0, 100) * 8.0]
dead = []
spared = []

dead_weight = 0.0

while in_trouble:
    m = np.median(list(set(random.sample(in_trouble, min(len(in_trouble), 5)))))
    print("Partitioning with pivot:", m)
    lighter_partition = []
    heavier_partition = []
    heavier_partition_weight = 0.0
    in_trouble_is_indivisible = True
    for p in in_trouble:
        if p < m:
            lighter_partition.append(p)
        else:
            heavier_partition.append(p)
            heavier_partition_weight += p
        if p != m:
            in_trouble_is_indivisible = False
    if heavier_partition_weight + dead_weight >= OVERWEIGHT and not in_trouble_is_indivisible:
        spared += lighter_partition
        in_trouble = heavier_partition
    else:
        dead += heavier_partition
        dead_weight += heavier_partition_weight
        in_trouble = lighter_partition

print("weight of dead people: {}; spared people: {}".format(
    dead_weight, sum(spared)))
print("Dead: ", dead)
print("Spared: ", spared)
```

Output:

```
Partitioning with pivot: 121.2
Partitioning with pivot: 158.9
Partitioning with pivot: 168.8
Partitioning with pivot: 161.5
Partitioning with pivot: 159.7
Partitioning with pivot: 158.9
weight of dead people: 3051.7; spared people: 9551.7
Dead:  [179.1, 182.5, 179.2, 171.6, 169.9, 179.9, 168.8, 172.2, 169.9, 179.6, 164.4, 164.8, 161.5, 163.1, 165.7, 160.9, 159.7, 158.9]
Spared:  [82.2, 91.9, 94.7, 116.5, 108.2, 78.9, 83.1, 114.6, 87.7, 103.0, 106.0, 102.3, 104.9, 117.0, 96.7, 109.2, 98.0, 108.4, 99.0, 96.8, 90.7, 79.4, 101.7, 119.3, 87.2, 114.7, 90.0, 84.7, 83.5, 84.7, 111.0, 118.1, 112.1, 92.5, 100.9, 114.1, 114.7, 114.1, 113.7, 99.4, 79.3, 100.1, 82.6, 108.9, 103.5, 89.5, 121.8, 156.1, 121.4, 130.3, 157.4, 138.9, 143.0, 145.1, 125.1, 138.5, 143.8, 146.8, 140.1, 136.9, 123.1, 140.2, 153.6, 138.6, 146.5, 143.6, 130.8, 155.7, 128.9, 143.8, 124.0, 134.0, 145.0, 136.0, 121.2, 133.4, 144.0, 126.3, 127.0, 148.3, 144.9, 128.1]
```

Comment: +1. This is an interesting idea, although I'm not certain that it's quite linear. Unless I'm missing something, you have to iterate over items in order to compute the total weight of the bucket, and you have to re-compute the high bucket (at least partially) every time you split. It'll still be faster than my heap-based approach in the general case, but I think you're underestimating the complexity.

Comment: @Jim: It should be the same complexity as [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm).  I know the description on wikipedia is not the best, but the reason that it's linear amortized time is that every time you do a partition, you work with only one side of the partition.  Non-rigorously, imagine each partition divides the set of people in two.  Then, the first step takes O(n), then O(n/2), etc.  and, n + n/2 + n/4 +... = 2n.

Comment: @Jim: Anyway, your algorithm has the best worst case time, while mine has the best average case time.  I think that they're both good solutions.

Comment: SoapBox's answer only goes over the entire list once, with constant extra space and time.  This is easy to see if you change the problem to "throw overboard the top 10 heaviest".

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't think that SoapBox's solution returns an optimal solution.  Also, are you sure that this solution is linear worst case? What if the pivots are bad?  Also, SoapBox's solution can't "throw overboard the top 10 heaviest" in one pass.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4250/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-neil-g)

Comment: I'd really like to understand those running times. It seems like the `std::set` approach and mine should be approximately the same. Is it because `std::set` is not implemented as a heap, whereas `std::priority_queue` (or whatever you used) is?

Comment: @JimMischel: I completely miswrote all three.  I'm debugging everything, then I'll put it back up.  At some point I replaced yours with a completely useless algorithm on accident.  Also, std::make_heap makes a vector into a heap.

Comment: @JimMischel, NeilG: http://codepad.org/FAx6hbtc  I verified all have the same results, and corrected Jim's.  FullSort: 1828 ticks.  JimMischel: 312 ticks.  SoapBox 109 ticks.  NeilG: 641 ticks.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If I'm reading that correctly, you've misinterpreted my algorithm. I don't make a heap with all of the items. My algorithm is very similar to SoapBox's algorithm: I only put something on the heap if the combined weight is less than the total desired, or if the current weight is heavier than the lowest item on the heap. You need to re-read my algorithm.

Comment: @JimMischel: Oh!  Yeah, I completely misread your algorithm.  Yours is the same as SoapBox's then.  Also, I realized I can make my version of NeilG's way faster.

Comment: @NeilG: http://codepad.org/0KmcsvwD  I used std::partition to make my implementation of your algorithm way faster. stdsort: 1812 ticks.  FullHeap 312 ticks.  Soapbox/JimMichel: 109 ticks, NeilG: 250 ticks.

Comment: @NeilG: I thought you might be interested in a more detailed analysis of heap select versus quick select. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/. Short version: in general, heap select will be faster when selecting less than 1% of the total number of items.

Comment: @JimMischel: Nice summary!  You could also use the term [online algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) to describe heap select.  :)

Comment: This solution ignores the OPs requirement that the passenger count is unknown in advance. " but I don't know how many elements I'm going to need." This eliminates arrays as a solution, as they are either arbitrarily large(bad) or have to be realloc()-ed,(badder) or overflowed(badest). If you don't know the size of the dataset in advance your options are Map,Set,List, and if sorted, forget List. Python may have you convinced it can do dynamic arrays, but there's no magic in computer science. Any solution based on arrays is unreliable. An STL Set is the optimal basis for a correct solution.

Comment: @user2548100: No, list insertion is amortized constant time.

Comment: @NeilG If this is a literal list, IE: a linked list, it's the slowest possible data structure of choice. If the "list" is actually an array, then it has all the prescribed problems. Using a language that pretends it can do things that can't be done is obscuring your vision. By way of example, I have invented a new language called ROI. It's sole purpose is to find the heaviest passengers in an indefinitely sized set. I can solve this problem in 1 line of code. Does that make it faster? Of course not. Benchmark your Python code. STL Set will be 10X as fast - at least.

Comment: @user2548100: A Python list is a dynamic array, which has amortized constant insertion cost. An "STL set" (which is typically a balanced binary search tree) only guarantees logarithmic insertion time.  It is asymptotically slower. Amortized constant time does not mean "one line of code".

Comment: @NeilG From Wikipedia on Linked-Lists, comparing linked-lists with dynamic arrays... " This helps with appending elements at the array's end, but inserting into (or removing from) middle positions still carries prohibitive costs due to data moving to maintain contiguity. An array from which many elements are removed may also have to be resized in order to avoid wasting too much space." For this problem, assuming the # of people are known at run-time, a simple malloc() will do, so I've over-engineered my answer above, but Python is not magic. It just obscures what it's doing under the covers.

Comment: @user2548100: Do you see anything other than appending elements at the array's end in the above algorithm?

Comment: @NeilG, not sure. I do see the OPs requirement that this be in STL, which supports vectors, which, given the # of passengers are known at runtime(vs compile time), means it will allocate an array of that size and be done with it. Solving DS&A problems in a language that obscures the details of what it's doing "under the covers" makes that language a poor choice.

Comment: @user2548100: Like C++, Python makes asymptotic guarantees and so hides as much as say `<algorithms>`.  If anything C++ obscures the algorithm by miring you in architectural details of data types, loop counters, etc.

Comment: @NeilG, the OP, apparently thinks those architectural details require hardware resources he'd like to keep front and center when considering performance and maintenance. I agree with him.

Comment: @user2548100: what are you talking about?  I was just illustrating an algorithm.  You can code it in C++ if you like.  What is the point of this rant or yours?

Comment: @NeilG, that you can't, and aren't meeting the OP's requirement that the answer be written in C++ using the STL.

Comment: @user2548100: If you don't think so, don't vote for my answer.

Comment: Once again we see the chronic mistake of thinking an algorithm with a lower complexity means it will run faster. All complexity tells you is what happens to performance as the set size increases WITHIN A GIVEN APPROACH. Complexity says NOTHING about the relative performance/run-time of different approaches/algorithms. If you want to know the relative performance of two different algorithms you need to benchmark them under conditions close to those of the production environment, or failing that, a well-constructed benchmark.

Comment: @NeilG, there's a boundary condition I've been wondering about. What happens if everyone weighs exactly the same amount? For the example given this wouldn't be a concern, but for a general purpose solution it would be.

Comment: @user2548100 The computational complexity measures asymptotic runtime. It can be compared between algorithms.

Comment: @user2548100 Please tone things down a bit. There's nothing wrong with discussing technical issues, but you *must* do so in a polite manner.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that, like people's weights, you have a good idea of what the maximum and minimum values are likely to be use a radix sort to sort them in O(n).  Then simply work from the heaviest end of the list towards the lightest.  Total running time: O(n).  Unfortunately, there isn't an implementation of a radix sort in the STL, but it's pretty straightforward to write.

Comment: I wouldn't use a general radix sort though, as you don't have to fully sort the list to derive the answer.

Comment: To clarify, a radix sort _is_ a good idea.  Just be sure to write a customized optimized one.

Comment: @Mooing: It is true that you don't have to do a complete radix sort, but at the time I posted this, there were no O(n) algorithms posted and this was an easy one to see.  I think that Neil G's answer is he best one now that he's explained it more fully and explicitly started using the median as the pivot for his selection.  But using a standard radix sort is slightly easier and less likely to have subtle implementation bugs, so I'm going to leave my answer up.  Doing a customized partial radix sort would definitely be faster, but not asymptotically so.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use a partial quicksort with a different abort rule than "sorted".
You can run it and then use just the higher half and go on until the weight within this higher half does not contain the weight that has at least to be thrown out anymore, than you go back one step in the recursion and sort the list. After that you can start throwing people out from the high end of that sorted list.

Comment: That's the basic concept behind Neil G's algorithm I _think_.

Comment: that's the essence of quickselect, which is what Neil G is using.

Answer (score 6):

Massively Parallel Tournament Sort:-

Assuming a standard three seats each side of the ailse:-

1. Ask the passengers in the window seat to move to the middle seat if they are heavier than the person in the window seat.
2. Ask the passengers in the middle seat to swap with the passenger in aisle seat if they are heavier.
3. Ask the passenger in the left aisle seat to swap with the passenger in the right aisle seat id they are heavier.
4. Bubble sort the passengers in the right aisle seat. (Takes n steps for n rows).
   -- ask the passengers in the right aisle seat to swap with the person in front n -1 times.

5  Kick them out the door until you reach 3000 pounds.

3 steps + n steps plus 30 steps if you have a really skinny passenger load.

For a two aisle plane -- the instructions are more complex but the performance is about the same.

Comment: same as Lior Kogan's answer, but much more detail.

Comment: A "good enough" solution would be to offer "free hotdogs" and throw out the first fifteen that reached the front. Will not provide the optimal solution every time but runs in plain "O".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to throw out the last 15 since the heavier ones will probably be slower?

Comment: @Patriker -- I believe the aim is to lose 3000 pounds with the minimum number of people. Although you could optimise the algorithm by change step 4 to "swap with the person in from n - 29 times" which would get the 30 porkiest to the front, though, not in strict order of weight.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use `std::nth_element` to partition off the 20 heaviest people in linear time. Then use a more complex method to find and bump off the heaviest of the heavies.

Answer (score 3):

You could make one pass over the list to get the mean and the standard deviation, then use that to approximate the number of people that have to go. Use partial_sort to generate the list based on that number. If the guess was low, use partial_sort again on the remainder with a new guess.

Answer (score 3):

@James has the answer in the comments:  a [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/) if you can use any container, or a combination of [`std::make_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) and [`std::pop_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/pop_heap/) (and [`std::push_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/)) if you want to use something like a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a heap-based solution using Python's built-in heapq module. It's in Python so doesn't answer the original question, but it's cleaner (IMHO) than the other posted Python solution.

```
import itertools, heapq

# Test data
from collections import namedtuple

Passenger = namedtuple("Passenger", "name seat weight")

passengers = [Passenger(*p) for p in (
    ("Alpha", "1A", 200),
    ("Bravo", "2B", 800),
    ("Charlie", "3C", 400),
    ("Delta", "4A", 300),
    ("Echo", "5B", 100),
    ("Foxtrot", "6F", 100),
    ("Golf", "7E", 200),
    ("Hotel", "8D", 250),
    ("India", "8D", 250),
    ("Juliet", "9D", 450),
    ("Kilo", "10D", 125),
    ("Lima", "11E", 110),
    )]

# Find the heaviest passengers, so long as their
# total weight does not exceeed 3000

to_toss = []
total_weight = 0.0

for passenger in passengers:
    weight = passenger.weight
    total_weight += weight
    heapq.heappush(to_toss, (weight, passenger))

    while total_weight - to_toss[0][0] >= 3000:
        weight, repreived_passenger = heapq.heappop(to_toss)
        total_weight -= weight


if total_weight < 3000:
    # Not enough people!
    raise Exception("We're all going to die!")

# List the ones to toss. (Order doesn't matter.)

print "We can get rid of", total_weight, "pounds"
for weight, passenger in to_toss:
    print "Toss {p.name!r} in seat {p.seat} (weighs {p.weight} pounds)".format(p=passenger)
```

If k = the number of passengers to toss and N = the number of passengers, then the best case for this algorithm is O(N) and the worst case for this algorithm is Nlog(N). The worst case occurs if k is near N for a long time. Here's an example of the worst cast:

```
weights = [2500] + [1/(2**n+0.0) for n in range(100000)] + [3000]
```

However, in this case (throwing people off the plane (with a parachute, I presume)) then k must be less than 3000, which is << "millions of people". The average runtime should therefore be about Nlog(k), which is linear to the number of people.